# Sharepoint 2013 Page Viewer Web Part iframe Links within page not working

Tags: iframe, sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 (Foundations I believe) and have a page where I have added a page viewer web part that points to a php file that resides on our old intranet site (it's a sales report).

The page displays fine on my Sharepoint page, however there are other links within that page that don't work when I click them on my Sharepoint page (the links point to other pages within page on our old intranet). For example, the page shows sales goals for a given period. There is a link or a toggle on the page that toggles the data between Retained Commission vs Written Commission. On the old page the link that you click goes to another link to toggle between the information.

Those links (and others) are not working because I suspect they are not referenced in the page viewer web part.  The Page Viewer Web Part references the location of the report within the web part, but how do I get the links within that page to work?  I'm suspecting that they don't work because they are not referenced somewhere?  But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe the page using Script Editor web part or Content Editor Web Part and  tag to check if it works.

And using IE F12 developer tools to check the HTML code. Check if all the  tags are not referenced in iframe page.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately that did not work.  On the second part, does it matter where in the code I insert the secondary hyperlinks for the additional references within the inserted page?